# how to wait for splash screen will be finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I want to wait for splash screen to finish his task and then to continue doing the activity.
I think  that my error is because too many time to wait for splash screen, my splash screen is for getting some string from server and its has all that need. 
the first class that creating and need to wait for splash screen finished  is:
Update:

```
            Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        splash  splash=(tools.splash) new splash(first.this).execute();
                        int waited = 0;
                        while(splash.running && (waited< getResources().getInteger(R.integer.splashTimeOut)))
                        {
                            sleep(100);
                            if(splash.running) {
                                waited += 100;
                            }
                            // nextActivity=splash.newActivity;
                        }
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        // do nothing
                    } finally {
                        finish();

                    }
                }
            };
            splashTread.start();
```

while the splash screen is ok its

```
  public class splash extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

its wrong because its create a new activity and then do the thread....

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   protected boolean _active = true;
   protected int _splashTime = 1000;
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                finish();

            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
```

Comment: I updated my code on the main post but still seemed its doing next activity and not waiting for thread (splash screen)

Answer (score 0):

I Hope My Code will be helpful to you

```
public void onStart() 
    {
        super.onStart();

        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    Intent langSelect = new Intent(EduApp.this, LanguageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(langSelect);
                    genHelper.goForwardScreen();
                }
                catch (Throwable t) 
                {               
                    System.err.println("Thread Exception IN Splash Screen->" + t.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        background.start();
    }
```

Start Next Activity Here..